# Ember dynamic segment is empty

Tags: ember.js

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/kt2Hz/

I have read the docs, api and browsed the source code of Ember. No luck!

**The routes:**

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource 'customers', path: 'my_customers', ->
    @resource 'customer', path: '/:customer_id', ->
      @route 'edit', path: '/my_edit'

App.CustomerEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set('content', model)
    alert("inspect: #{Ember.inspect(model)}")
```

The alert output is "inspect: undefined"

And if I check the params, the object is empty:

```
App.CustomerEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    alert("inspect: #{Ember.inspect(params)}")
```

The alert output is "inspect: {}"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the dynamic segment is only passed to the customer route, not the nested ones. so if you change the model hook in your `CustomerEditRoute` to

```
model: (params) ->
    return this.modelFor("customer")
```

it should work.

(pretty much the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165892/how-to-create-a-right-structure-for-nested-routes-in-ember-js) btw.)

Comment: Do you know if this is by design or a missing implementation in Ember?

Comment: i think it's by design, but i don't know for sure.